# Azure Web App update

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

We have created the Web applications and we have a plan to publish the application as Web App in Azure Marketplace. Publishing the Web App to Marketplace can be done using ARM templates(POC) for one-click deployment for our customers.

When we release the newer version of the application, how can we provide the seamless upgrade to our customers through the Azure Marketplace like Google Play Store (Install button for 1st time and Update button for older version use users?

I came through this article explained the deployment in Azure. But, i didn't find any article for Upgrade Azure App

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy

Answer (score 1):

We can use git pull command to get the updates from other git repository. In Azure kudu, the command could be like this,

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot>git remote add gitsource https://username@passwordyourgitserver.com/xx.git
D:\home\site\wwwroot>git pull gitsource master
```

> When we release the newer version of the application, how can we provide the seamless upgrade to our customers

After released the new version of your application, you could force your client to execute upper command to get the updates. If you use C# as your programming language, you could use following steps to execute powershell command.

1. Install System.Management.Automation dll using NuGet.
2. Run powershell scripts using following method.

```
private static string RunScript(string scripts)
{
    // create Powershell runspace
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    // open it
    runspace.Open();
    // create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scripts);
    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
    //execute the script
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    //close the runspace
    runspace.Close();
    // convert the script result into a single string
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ARM template you use to provision the site for the customer, you can enable continuous deployment to that site from a GitHub repo. So anytime that repo is updated, the website (any or all of them) provisioned by your template will be update with the new drop.

See this sample template: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-github-deploy

And then for automated deployments set this to "false":

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-github-deploy/azuredeploy.json#L101